# Groovy PostBuild's object called 'manager' isn't accessible inside the groovy script I am calling in one of the stage of Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

```
node(NODE){
stages {
        stage('first') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('run myScript'){
           sh "groovy folderName/myScript"
       }

    }

}
```

myScript.groovy looks like:

```
class MyScript{
  static{
    //initializing some varibles
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //logic to do some task
    // the logic populates a arraylist which I want to print on build page using 'manager' object //by PostBuild
     def summary_manager = manager.createSummary("green_anime.gif");
     manager.addShortText("Blocked: $num");
     summary_manager.appendText("<h3>Number of Blocked Users: $num</h3>", false);
  }
}
```

But I cant access the object manager inside the script.
I tried passing it as an argument to groovy script in jenkins file as

```
sh "groovy folderName/myScript ${manager}"
```

when I tried print argument in myScript it print that it is indeed the object of manager object I am looking for but when I call methods such as:

```
manager.createSummary("dfd.gif);
```

it says it cannot find the appropriate method signature for this method.

Although this works when I call this methods in Jenkinsfile itself in any one of the stage, but it doesn't work when I try to call it inside the myScript.groovy.

Why? can someone please help I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the script as a new Shell process. So it runs on a different Groovy runtime and will not have access to objects from the pipeline. So try loading the script to the Pipeline and then execute it.

**Script**

```
def createSummary(def manager) {
     def summary_manager = manager.createSummary("green_anime.gif");
     manager.addShortText("Blocked: $num");
     summary_manager.appendText("<h3>Number of Blocked Users: $num</h3>", false);
}

return this;
```

**Pipeline**

```
def scriptObj = load "groovy folderName/myScript.groovy"
scriptObj.createSummary(manager)
```